# Scala Error: type mismatch found :(Int, Int) => Int required: Ordering[Int]

Tags: scala

While running the following code in scala, the error Type mismatch is throwing

```
private def currentOrd: Ordering[Int] = 
    if (isAscending) (x: Int, y: Int) => x+y
    else (x: Int, y: Int) => y - x
```

Answer (score 0):

Just what the error says: your code says it's supposed to return `Ordering[Int]`, but it returns a function. In Scala 2.12 a function literal can be automatically converted to a single-abstract-method trait like `Ordering` (and your code will compile), but not in 2.11 or before.

Separately from that, `(x: Int, y: Int) => x+y` is quite unlikely to be right; if you meant `(x: Int, y: Int) => x - y` then a better way to write it (which works in previous versions too) is

```
if (isAscending) Ordering.Int else Ordering.Int.reverse
```